# Export a workload log on YCSB

Tags: access-log, ycsb, workload-scheduler

just learned that YCSB can run some predefined workloads. Is it possible to export a workload log? In other words, it is expected that the workload log can include some features for each access record, such as

1.operation: read, insert, or update
2. key: a key id
3. value: the value of a key
4. timestamp: when to execute the operation.

Is that possible for YCSB?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you probably need display this information from whatever database system you're using. The output of YCSB is rather limited.

Comment: Hi, River. I installed Redis as the DB for my YCSB. Intuitively, YCSB can generate a workload. I am currently studying the patterns of user traces to a DB. So, I expect to get an access pattern like the following situation. 
->at time T1, operation insert, key x1, value 10
->at time T2, operation insert, key x2, value 11
->at time T3, operation read, key x1
->at time T4, operation update, key x3, value 5....
Is it possible for YCSB to generate a workload log like the above example?

Comment: I think you'd probably need to edit the YCSB source code to generate this output. It probably wouldn't be that hard tho. Look at option 2 [here](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Implementing-New-Workloads)

Comment: Thanks for River. I am trying to check if it is possible to generate this output on YCSB.